# How does a kernel come to know that the CPU is idle?

Tags: linux, operating-system, kernel, scheduler, processor

I was studying Operating Systems and am stuck on a doubt that when a currently running process on the processor requests for some I/O, the CPU becomes idle and the scheduler then schedules another process to execute on the CPU. How does the kernel here come to know that the CPU has become idle. Is there some kind of hardware interrupt sent by the processor?

Comment: The kernel is giving work to the CPU (in its scheduler). When no work can be given, the kernel knows that the CPU needs to become idle (and wait for something, e.g. some interrupt)

Answer (score 1):

The OS 'knows' that a CPU needs to become idle when it performs a scheduling run and has fewer ready threads than cores.

If the scheduler runs and has only two ready threads that can use CPU, but has four actual cores available, then it will direct the 'surplus' cores to an 'idle' thread that is a loop around a 'HLT', or like instruction, that causes the core to stop fetching and executing instructions until an interrupt is received.

Answer (score 0):

In my option, the kernel always running on the CPU, and the kernel knows schedule which process or interrupt handler.

Comment: No, the kernel is only entered when there is a need for it - upon a syscall or entry from a driver after a hardware interrupt.